# catching errors with using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, binarywriter

I am using a using with the BinaryWriter as follows:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(configData.RxOutFn, FileMode.Create)))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Sometimes I have the file open in another app, and the Create fails, how can I catch this error?

I tried putting a try/catch around the whole thing like this:

```
try
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(configData.RxOutFn, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        // Do something                    
    }
}
catch
{
    // Display error
}
```

But I am worried it will catch the wrong thing as there is lots of code in the

```
// Do Something
```

Any ideas how i can catch this error?

Many thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: Just catch the specific exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what exception gets thrown (`File.Open` throws an `IOException` which I think is what gets thrown when the file can't be created) and catch that specific exception:

```
try
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(configData.RxOutFn, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        // Do something                    
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // Display error
}
```